# Android application crash at start (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin and I try to develop a (very) little quizz for Android but when I start the app, it crash. I've already check but I don't see any error.

Here an extract of my code.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Welcome on Quizzer !.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    setLevel()
    checkAnswer()
}
```

Here my full code : https://pastebin.com/U6xtnC5c

Logcat :

```
2020-04-12 17:15:10.783 10645-10645/com.madijason.quizzer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.madijason.quizzer, PID: 10645
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.madijason.quizzer/com.madijason.quizzer.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
    at com.madijason.quizzer.MainActivity.setLevel(MainActivity.kt:53)
    at com.madijason.quizzer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, as well as the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174). Please don't link to necessary code or XML off-site.

Comment: you are not even calling .show for your toast .?
add logs as well

Comment: Show your app logs in Logcat to us please.

Comment: @ImanX, I've been added it

Comment: I think issue is about your 2 methods used.

Comment: do u use array in app? because your log show crash from `Array`, Likely use `Array` in one of methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
```

You are getting **`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`**. You should set start index from  0.

> [**`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown to indicate that we are
>   trying to access array element with an illegal index.

```
   first_answer.text = thirdQuestionAnswer[0]
   second_answer.text = thirdQuestionAnswer[1]
   third_answer.text = thirdQuestionAnswer[2]
   fourth_answer.text = thirdQuestionAnswer[3]
```

Comment: That doesn't really explain the crash that the OP says is happening.

Comment: Thank you. I've been correct all my Toast but the app keep crashing.

Comment: @BasilVolodin show error log with full code

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, how can I have logs ? EDIT: Full code is on Pastebin